# Bluetooth LE Client Characteristic Configuration Descriptorの書き込み方法について

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

iOSにおいて、「Characteristic Configuration Descriptor」に「2(0x02)」を書き込みIndicateを許可する方法について教えていただけないでしょうか。

CBPeripheralクラスの

```
- (void)writeValue:(NSData )data forDescriptor:(CBDescriptor )descriptor;
```

を利用したところ、
　「setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic: を使うべきです。」

とのエラーが発生しました。

なお、Androidでは以下のコードで実現済みです。
これと同じことをiOSで実現したいと考えております。

```java
BluetoothGattService s = 
  mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString(サービスUUID));

BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic2 = 
  s.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(characteristicのUUID));

int charaProp = characteristic2.getProperties();
                   mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic2, true);

// Sensor の notification 機能を有効化する
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = 
　characteristic2.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(DESCRIPTOR_UUID));
                    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);

// 設定した descriptor を書き込む
mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

Comment: iOSでは権限の関係でdescriptorの値がソース上では変更できない場合があるようです。 
そちらの観点で考え直してみたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

メッセージに書かれた [`setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheral/setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:) を呼べば、Characteristic 上の宣言に基づいて Notification と Indication のどちらか適切な方を許可するよう設定されます。

技術的にはNotificationとIndicationの主な違いは応答を返すかどうかなので、iOSにせよAndroidにせよこの違いはライブラリ側で吸収されています。その上で、Androidは手動で当該Descriptorを変更することができますが、iOSは `setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:` を使うよう強制している、という話です。

なおAndroidでも同じようにNotification/Indicationのどちらかを許可するメソッド、 [`setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic, boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#setCharacteristicNotification(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20boolean)) があるようです。

参考

- [- setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic: - CBPeripheral Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheral/writeValue:forDescriptor:)
- [【連載】Bluetooth LE (2) iOS デバイスで Bluetooth LE 機器を使う (フェンリル | デベロッパーズブログ)](http://blog.fenrir-inc.com/jp/2013/10/bluetooth-le-ios-1.html)
- [Handling indications instead of notifications in Android BLE - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030718/handling-indications-instead-of-notifications-in-android-ble)